# Why should I use "of" after more?

Tags: prepositions

> Do more of what makes you happy.

Why do we have to use "of" after more?
Can I just say do more what makes you happy? (I know we should not say it like this, but I do not know why.) I know I have to use more + noun.

Answer (score 1):

Determiners and adjectives cannot be placed in front of pronouns. The 'what' is a pronoun, and the 'more' is either a determiner or an indefinite pronoun ('makes you happy' modifies the 'what'). You cannot place the determiner 'more' in front of the 'what', so the other solution is to use the structure 'indefinite pronoun + of + N(P)'. This is why. Hope I helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can't remove the preposition from your example sentence, because "what makes you happy" isn't a noun. "Of" is needed to indicate the relationship between a verb and what follows.

For example:

> - Can I have more *juice*?
> - Can I have more **of** *that lovely orange juice*?

Answer (score 0):

I'm no grammarian but let me throw some facts into he ring.

> Do more of what makes you happy.

In your sentence, the direct object of the verb *do* is 'more' (noun). Since *more* is a noun here, we need the preposition 'of' to separate it from the next noun 'what' (also a noun here) because (as far as I know) we cannot have two nouns right next to each other.

So saying "do *more what* makes you happy" would be incorrect (redundant?) because we can't have two nouns right next to each other.

Now consider the sentence below:

> Do more things that make you happy

You might be wondering that *more* and *things* are used next to each other and it is not redundant. The reason is that *more* is an adjective in this case and *things* is a noun, so it is possible.